# How to draw the graph of $F(x,y)=0$ for given $F$.

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, graphing-functions

Are there general method for drawing the graph of $F(x,y)=0$ for given $F$?
What if $F$ is a polynomial?

Comment: What are you using to graph the set of points? A calculator/computer or are you doing it by hand?

Comment: See Tupper, “Reliable two-dimensional graphing methods for mathematical formulae with two free variables”: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf

Comment: An algorithm is described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120582/contour-graphing-algorithm/1121368#1121368).

Comment: @Matti P. I'm using Python and want to know algorithm.